# Crontab Python Script not running

Tags: python, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I know this question has been asked before but I still haven't been able to get it to work. My crontab file just has this:

```
0 5 * * * /home/harry/my_env/bin/python /home/harry/compile_stats/process_tonight.py
```

Here's what my process_tonight.py looks like:

```
import datetime
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/harry/compile_stats/')
import compile   # Module in above path

print("Processing last night\n")

date = str(datetime.datetime.today().year) + "-" + str(datetime.datetime.today().month) + "-" + str(datetime.datetime.today().day-1)

compile.process(date, date)
```

This file works perfectly fine when I just run it regularly from the command line but doesn't work when I schedule it.

I also looked at my /var/log/syslog file and the task I'm looking to run isn't showing up there.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
The time it's set to run in my example (5 A.M) is just a random time to put in. It's not running for any time I put in there.

**EDIT 2#:**

As per user speedyturkey I simplified my python script to better diagnose the problem:

```
import datetime
#import sys
#sys.path.append('/home/harry/compile_stats/')
#import compile   # Module in above path

print("Processing last night\n")

date = str(datetime.datetime.today().year) + "-" + str(datetime.datetime.today().month) + "-" + str(datetime.datetime.today().day-1)

#compile.process(date, date)
```

Nothing is happening so I guess the problem isn't with the import.

Comment: Which crontab file did you use? Is it /etc/crontab, /etc/cron.d/somthng, /etc/cron.hourly, /var/spool/cron/username? How did you add the line there? With which command? Or just by editing?

Comment: @SergeyVasilyev I opened it using "crontab -e" and I just added it in there (using vim if that matters). Typing "crontab -l" shows the contents I've added

Comment: Probably obvious, but that will make it run at 5am every day. Have you waited a full 24 hours to make sure that system time isn't just set weirdly or something?

Comment: @Xorgon Check the edit I just made. It's just a random time I put. It's not running in general  for any time.

Comment: have you changed any file permissions recently in cron dir? What's the output of `ls -l /etc/cron.allow; cat /etc/cron.allow`

Comment: To clarify: When you say "run it regularly from the command line", I assume you literally do `/home/harry/my_env/bin/python /home/harry/compile_stats/process_tonight.py`?

Comment: @Xorgon Yes. Well I already activated my virtualenev so I just python instead of the first command.

Comment: Try doing it exactly as you have it in the crontab.

Comment: @Xorgon I don't think it would work though. It would invoke the standard python interpreter which isn't what I want.

Comment: @medigeek I've never touched the file permissions.

Comment: "cron invokes the command from the user’s HOME directory with the shell, (/usr/bin/sh)."

_(From: http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)_

So cron will run it as you would run it by default.

Comment: Can you show the output of the commands I have asked before? It's essential to debug this issue

Comment: @medigeek Sorry, here you go "ls: cannot access '/etc/cron.allow': No such file or directory
cat: /etc/cron.allow: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, I believe the problem is in how you are calling the python script in the crontab. Run the exact command you've given crontab and fix any problems it returns.

Comment: Sorry, that's not it. I ran the exact command and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you run it from a cold login? No prior environment setup etc.?

Comment: Just ran it from a cold login (and no setup). Works fine

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to get it to work by creating a specific cron file, putting the info and there and loading it in.

So process_tonight.cron contains this:

```
0 5 * * * /home/harry/my_env/bin/python /home/harry/compile_stats/process_tonight.py
```

And I just loaded it into crontab:

```
crontab process_tonight.cron
```

Not really sure why this works and the other way doesn't (maybe someone else has an idea).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to modify the path from within your python script, you could do something like:

`cd /home/harry/compile_stats/ && ./process_tonight.py`

which would make it easier to `import compile` correctly. Note that this would also require making process_tonight.py executable (`chmod +x process_tonight.py`) and adding a shebang pointing to your Python interpreter (I guess... #!/home/harry/my_env/bin/python).

EDIT in response to Edit #2 above:
It is actually not possible to tell if it is running from the code you have written - the print statements are not being redirected. I suggest changing the code to perform some kind of side effect that you can check. For example, import subprocess and then do (example):

`subprocess.call("date > /home/harry/compile_stats/date.txt")`

If the script is executed properly, it will redirect the output of `date` to the file specified.

Comment: You may also wish to simplify your Python script until you solve your cron issue...it is hard to tell whether your Python script isn't being called at all, or is being called and is failing (perhaps due to an import issue).

Comment: Check my recent edit. I simplified it and it still isn't running. Guess it's not the import

Comment: I added an edit to my answer in response. This is a tricky diagnosis, but I feel like you're getting closer!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit silly, but checking your system time/timezone might be helpfull )))
I set my job to run at 5AM and when I logged in at 8AM there was no result of my script. So I spent over 1 hour trying to figure out what's the problem before I noticed that system time is incorrect and 5AM haven't come yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it from a shell script? I was having the same issue with my python script. I ended up putting the command in a shell script and running that. It threw an error that the library wasn't imported, so I installed it with pip and the --user flag. Now cron runs the shell script no issues.